# Problema com input em um looping

Tags: python

Estou fazendo uma calculadora e como entrada de dados eu preciso apenas de números, caso o usuário digite algo diferente aparece uma mensagem dizendo "*Digite um número inteiro!*" e o input retorna. O problema que estou tendo é:
Se o primeiro input o usuário digitar um número inteiro o código passa pro segundo input, mas caso o usuário digite diferente o código volta pro **primeiro** input. O que eu tenho que fazer para continuar no segundo input e não retornar pro primeiro?

Atualmente tenho o básico:

```py
while True:  # Receber dados e verificar se é um número;
    num1 = input('Digite o primeiro numero inteiro: ')
    if num1.isdigit():
        num1 = int(num1)
        num2 = input('Digite o segundo numero inteiro: ')
        if num2.isdigit():
            num2 = int(num2)
            break
    else:
        print('Digite um numero inteiro!')
```

Comment: Faça dois whiles, um para o primeiro numero e outro para o segundo, ou então faça uma variavel auxiliar para fora do while que poderia ser a propria num1 com valor None e cheque dentro do while se a primeira var é `if num1 is None:`, se for, então solicite o `num1 = input('Digite o primeiro numero inteiro: ')` se não for significa que já obteve o valor de num1 e pode continuar.

Comment: **Observação**, o problema aqui não tem haver com checar se a variável com isdigit (portanto não é duplicata, então o motivo do fechamento foi alterado) e não tem motivo algum para usar isinstance, o problema é só a lógica para checar o que já foi atribuído as variáveis.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

opa, e aí!

você pode usar a função isinstance() para verificar se uma variável é uma instância de um determinado tipo, como float ou int.

## Solicita ao usuário o primeiro número

num1 = input(f'Digite o primeiro numero: ')

## Verifica se o primeiro número é um float ou int

if isinstance(num1, float) or isinstance(num1, int):

## Converte o primeiro número para um float

num1 = float(num1)
else:

## Gera um erro se o primeiro número não for um float ou int

raise ValueError("O primeiro numero nao e um inteiro ou um flutuante.")

## Solicita ao usuário o segundo número

num2 = input(f'Digite o segundo numero: ')

## Verifica se o segundo número é um float ou int

if isinstance(num2, float) or isinstance(num2, int):

## Converte o segundo número para um float

num2 = float(num2)
else:

## Gera um erro se o segundo número não for um float ou int

raise ValueError("O segundo numero nao e um inteiro ou um flutuante.")

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).